# В чем ошибка конвертации opentele?

Tags: python, telegram

Я конвертирую файл tdata в session формат, но мне выдает такую ошибку, интересно то, что раньше такой ошибки не было

Вот ошибка, которую я получаю[image: Ошибка]

Мой код

```
from opentele.td import TDesktop
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession
import asyncio

async def main():

    # Load TDesktop client from tdata folder
    directory = 'tdata'

    tdataFolder = str(directory)#str(directory)
    tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)
    print('Файл загружен OK')

    #print('Файл загружен с кодом C1')
 
    # Check if we have loaded any accounts
    assert tdesk.isLoaded()

    # flag=UseCurrentSession
    #
    # Convert TDesktop to Telethon using the current session.
    client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)

    # Connect and print all logged-in sessions of this client.
    # Telethon will save the session to telethon.session on creation.
    await client.connect()
    await client.PrintSessions()

asyncio.run(main())
```

[image: Как у меня располагаются файлы]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что вы новичок. По вашему коду это видно. Скажу сразу, что в данном случае в переменную нет смысла засовать другую переменную:

```
directory = 'tdata'

tdataFolder = str(directory)#str(directory)
```

Ещё добавлю, что `tdataFolder` может быть названа как угодно (это если вы не знали), главное, чтобы дальше в коде она также называлась.

Дальше вам стоит научиться читать (или хотя бы перевести через переводчик), то что написано в ошибке. А там в конце ошибки написана сома причина: `Exception: No account has been loaded` Перевод: `Неожиданное исключение: учетная запись не была загружена`

По этому можно понять, что она не нашла аккаунт (то есть путь до него). Вам просто нужно скопировать тот код взятый от сюда: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457819/how-to-convert-tdata-to-telethon-session` оставить его как есть или просто вот так:

```
from opentele.td import TDesktop
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession, CreateNewSession
import asyncio


async def main():
    # Load TDesktop client from tdata folder
    tdataFolder = "tdata"
    tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)

    # Check if we have loaded any accounts
    assert tdesk.isLoaded()

    # 1)   Использовать текущий сеанс:
    # 1) flag=UseCurrentSession #
    # 1) Convert TDesktop to Telethon using the current session.
    client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)

    # 2)   Создать новый сеанс:
    # 2) flag=CreateNewSession #
    # 2) Convert TDesktop to Telethon by creating a new session.
    # 2) CreateNewSession will use the current session (in tdata folder) to authorize a new session using QR Login.
    # 2) If 2FA is enabled for this account, you must specify the password via the password argument.
    # 2) This is of course slower than UseCurrentSession.
    # client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=CreateNewSession)


    # Connect and print all logged-in sessions of this client.
    # Telethon will save the session to telethon.session on creation.
    await client.connect()
    await client.PrintSessions()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Работает не трогай :)

Comment: Не думаю, что кто-то бы ответил тебе на этот вопрос. 
Я даже решил зарегаться, чтобы помочь :)

Comment: Добавлю что str переводит в текст, а не в путь до файла.